# How to embed https://www.youtube.com/ with iframe or another option by my website

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to show http://www.youtube.com to a child page of my website. I use for this iframe html

```
iframe src="https://www.youtube.com"></iframe>
```

This is a result
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GywEy.png)

And how legal it is in production

Comment: YouTube does not let you do that. They send the response header `X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN`, which tells browsers, that this site does not _want_ to be shown in (i)frames on different domains.

Comment: Check your browser's development console for the error(s) that you're getting.  It will provide you with information you can use to research the problem.  *"And how legal it is in production"* - Stack Overflow does not provide legal advice.  You are encouraged to consult an attorney for that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know that is legal and safe to do is creating embeds to YouTube videos and being able to watch them on your website. You can get the embed code of any video on YouTube by right-clicking on a YouTube video and clicking on the copy embed code then just paste it into your html code.

Hope that's helpful!